# Check for UITextField calls

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I am using this function:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
      shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
      replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
}
```

Inside the above function I want to check which textfield I am currently dealing with, can I put a check on on that particular textfield and secondly I want to compare say textfieldB.text when I end editing it (textfieldB) to another field say textfieldA.text, are the above two scenarios possible, I appreciate in advance for any help

Comment: ok i found the solution 
textfield.tags would do what i want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are IBOutlets and declared in your interface then you can have if statements to check which textfield you are dealing with (i.e if(textField == textFieldA){doSomething;}
else if (textField ==...

Also if the textFieldA are tagged (you an tag them in interface builder) then you can have a switch statement to test each case.
Switch (textField.tag){...}.

You should also make you UIViewController class a "UITextFieldDelegate" and you can call a similar - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing... And make a similar comparison there.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try using the UITextFieldDelegate it would be better as you would not have to check for tags.

Comment: i want the function to work for say 2 out of 5 textfields, then tags would do the solution :)

Comment: Then you should delegate only those. In future if you plan to change something and increase then it would not be feasible to keep you using tags. Never the less tag is also a way of doing it. Good luck!

Comment: will you suggest a link for any such example

Comment: Use  myTextFeild.delegate=self; in .m (viewdidload) file for all the text field that you want this functionality and use '<UITextFieldDelegate>' in ur .h file. Sorry i dont know any tutorial on this but you could read about UITextFieldDelegate.